# Single-spa application issue with child app routing

Tags: angular, single-spa-angular

I have set up a single-spa root-config app and other 2 child apps implemented in angular (using parcels). And I'm trying to navigate to child app routes from root app, it works for the first route `/app1`, but from that, if I want to navigate to `/app1/search or /app1/details` it doesn't load the associated component, although url is changed.

If I initially hit `/app1/search` it loads search component, but after that, if I try to navigate to other routes like `/app1/<any-route>` it changes the url, but doesn't load the components.

```
providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/app1' }] in app-routing.module.ts
```

If you set your APP_BASE_URL with `/` you'll have to add `/app1` prefix in all links and routes, but it doesn't work.